# What does "skill" mean as a verb?

Tags: meaning

*To skill the ecosystem, partnership is important.*

I heard this, and I couldn't find the meaning of skill as a verb. What does skill mean in this context?

Comment: Where did you take the sentence from?

Comment: It's classical verbing of a noun.

Comment: The verb _reskill_ (T and I) is in common use ([Oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com...reskill](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/reskill)) and sometimes the 'training from the beginning' meaning is required instead. Increasingly common; sometimes with _up_ ('skill the refuges up').

Comment: Yes, this is an obvious case of 'verbing' a noun, but even after one realises this, the intended meaning is likely to remains puzzling to most people: what exactly is it to give an ecosystem (something that most people do not regard as conscious) a skill (something that only a conscious being can have)? It may, perhaps, be accepted in the circles to which the author belongs that ecosystems should be spoken about as conscious beings, whether metaphorically or literally, but this is not how most people speak and think of them.

Comment: You may wish to note that there is another contributor to this site who has the same username. (It is surprising that the Stack Exchange software does not automatically provide warnings about such duplications.)

Answer (score 0):

My copy of the SOED lists only one candidate sense:

1. Understand; determine (dialectical; transitive verb)

There's another archaic meaning of [**Avail; help**], but it's intransitive.

Answer (score 0):

There is a tendency among some people who wish to appear fashionable to use nouns as verbs. In fact, there is an American English saying **"There ain't no noun that can't be verbed"**. (= You can change any noun into a verb.")

And this is what the writer of *to skill the ecosystem, partnership is important* has done. In this case I would take it to mean *"**In order** to give skills to the ecosystem, partnership is important"* which, in turn, means *"**In order to enable** the ecosystem **to cope** with the things that threaten to damage it, partnership is important."*

I suggest you avoid "verbing nouns".